# Sencha Touch Charts - group by field

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-charts

I have in a tabPanel a list from a Store who's based on the Model below. In the second tab I want a pie-chart (build with Sencha Charts 2.0 Beta) with the total number of three possible values of my **vote** field (values can be "Yes", "No" or "AB", so what I expect is three pie-parts).

The Store grouper function group the store by **name** first character for the list.

```
groupFn: function(record) {                
            return record.get('name')[0].toUpperCase();                        
        }
```

I thought about creating a new Store dynamically BUT the number of data is very large (~31k rows in DB) so if i can handle with the Store I already have it would be great.

Model :

```
{
  name : 'someName',
  vote : 'someVote',
  ID   : 'someID'
}
```

Hope I give all the informations.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK update, now I have the total number for each vote result. I used the following code :

```
var store = Ext.getCmp('myList').getStore();                            
store.findBy(function(rec) {
        if (rec.get('vote') === 'YES') {
              countYES++;
           } 
});
```

I'm trying to use those data in my pie chart now.

Comment: Solve my problem. I create a new Store with result of my count function above.